# Kernel of an undirected graph with cycles 4 and 5

Tags: graph-theory

The definition of a kernel is:

(a) no two vertices in V' are joined by an edge, and

(b) for every v ∈ V - V' there is a vertex u ∈ V' such that (v, u) ∈ E.

I've been trying to find pictured examples of graphs and their kernel (particularly with cycles 4 and 5), but can not find any good examples on google.

Please show the graphs, or point me to a resource/stackexchange question.

Comment: What do you mean by "graphs with cycles 4 and 5"?

Comment: A graph containing a cycle with length 4, and a graph containing a cycle with length 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw such a graph as follows:

1. Draw any graph you like. Make sure it has cycles lengths 4 or 5 if
   required. These vertices will form $V-V'$.
2. Add new vertices. These will be the required kernel. No edges
   between these. to make it easier, place these "outside" the original graph.
3. For each vertex not in the kernel, add an edge to at least one
   kernel vertex.

That is is!